How to fix 'incomplete bitcode' error in .net-ios app?
I am using NET-iOS.Naxam.FSCalendar package in net8.0-ios app and uploading its ipa to Transporter. During verification, Transporter gives the following error:

Invalid Bundle Executable. The executable file
'Mobile.app/Frameworks/FSCalendar.framework/FSCalendar' contains
incomplete bitcode. To compile binaries with complete bitcode, open
Xcode and choose Archive in the Product menu.

Seems like there is some issue in the Native Reference(FSCalendar) used in NET-iOS.Naxam.FSCalendar package, but I'm not able to figure out.
